# ffmpeg concatenate results in bad/garbled output for second input file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate two videos together using the ffmpeg concat demuxer: a 5-second intro splash and a 60-second main/body video. I understand that the encoding needs to be the same on both files for this to work. I think they are, but the resulting output shows the intro just fine, followed by a totally garbled body. What am I missing?

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Contents of `concat.txt`:

```
file 'intro.mp4'
file 'body.mp4'
```

and the output of `ffprobe` for both input files:

**intro.mp4**

```
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 73 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 69 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

**body.mp4**

```
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'body.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:00:36.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5615 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 5613 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

**Output of ffmpeg:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fdda3018000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'concat.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 69 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 69 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 69 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fdda3800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
frame= 1047 fps=973 q=-1.0 Lsize=   25299kB time=00:00:41.76 bitrate=4962.8kbits/s speed=38.8x    
video:25286kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.050621%
```

As far as I can tell, everything is identical except for the bitrate and language. Setting the language doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried to transcode the intro to a higher bitrate for the intro but can't get it to stick in the output. I'm OK with transcoding one of the files (ideally the intro) but don't know what else to try to change. Thoughts?

Comment: What does mediainfo say for the two files? Especially Reference frames count.

Comment: @Mulvya: Awesome, thanks. I didn't know about mediainfo. The crf was different between the two. Setting them to be the same fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of @Mulvya, I used `mediainfo` to inspect the files and noticed that the two had been encoded with different `crf` settings. Re-encoding the intro with the same `crf` resulted in a working concatenated file.

Comment: CRF shouldn't make a difference. Likely, some thing else, like b-pyramid..etc.